# Django: How to translate the models' fields

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

I'm using the internationalization of django to translate my web app. I look this tutorial for that

http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/internationalization-localization-languages-time-zones

But I want to know how to translate the fields of my models with the internationalization of django or how I can translate my models' fields

Thanks a lot!

Comment: maybe this plugin is useful: [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation)

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a bit late, but anyway...

The best solution I have found for myself is to add additional fields to models like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    name_fr = models.CharField(help_text='MyModel name in French')
    # and so on for every language you want
```

And then assuming that you have `{% load i18n %}` and passed `mymodel` as `MyModel` object to your template:

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
<h1>{% if LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en-US' %}{{ mymodel.name }}{% elif LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr-FR' %}{{ mymodel.name_fr }}{% endif %}</h1>
```

This statements must not be strictly like that. You can implement another logic but this is how I did already in a couple of projects. Also you can pass `LANGUAGE_CODE` from view if you wish so.

P.S. If you want your application to support a lot of languages, then it might get a little bit dirty in templates with plenty of `if` statements and in admin panel provided by Django.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of Django applications that help you with this:

- [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) - Fairly popular, automatically adds columns for you.
- [django-parler](https://github.com/django-parler/django-parler) - Somewhat popular, creates a separate table for translated values.
- [django-translated-field](https://github.com/matthiask/django-translated-fields) - Newer, lightweight approach that automatically adds columns.

Alternatively, if you already have translated text in your `django.po` file, you can `trans` the model like so:

```
{% trans mymodel.name %}
```